# ScrollToItem isn't working properly

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, collectionview

I have a horizontal collection view of buttons. When one of them is clicked, the user is taken to another view controller. Often times not all buttons are visible, so what I would like, is for the selected button to be of the left most side of the collection view.

I was attempting to do that with the scrollToItem function. The problem is, that it keeps scrolling the collection view all the way to the right each time.

Relevant code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return labelArray.count
}

//frees up the collection view when the scroll is active
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    isScrolling = true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    //possible problem
    if isScrolling == false {
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.left, animated: false)
    }

    let myLabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

    let myArray = labelArray[indexPath.row]

    myLabel.text = labelArray[indexPath.row]
    myLabel.textColor = UIColor.white

    if myArray == labelArray[1] {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 56/255, green: 120/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 1)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. All I did was change

```
if isScrolling == false {
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.left, animated: false)
}
```

to

```
if isScrolling == false {
    let i = IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: i, at: .right, animated: false)
}
```

Previously it would scroll to each cell without stopping at each individual one.

So for each item I hard code the value dependent on which section that is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the scrollToItem method in the cellForItemAt method, which is called for every visible cell in your collection view. So you are essentially trying to scroll to each cell as it becomes visible. Try calling the scrollToItem method in the didSelectItemAt method like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
}
```

The didSelectItemAt is only called when a cell is selected and provides the IndexPath of the selected cell.

Comment: So I did try implementing this in didSelectItemAt method. It does stop the collection view from scrolling to the right side at start, the problem is that it's not doing anything to it.

Comment: I tested that the code above, see edit, works in a simple collection view app that I built.  Without seeing how you implemented the didSelectItemAt method or the rest of the code in your class, I'm not sure where your issue is.

Comment: I got it to work in cellForItemAt method. Just had to hard code the item index. I'll post the answer. Thanks for your help tho.

Comment: How can you hard code the item index? That index will be based on which item the user selects.

Comment: I really meant the indexPath.